# How does unequal in javascript work?

Tags: javascript, operators

So basically I assume that there is something about equal/unequal that I didn't quite understand.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript#1144249

Comment: `==` only looks at basic values, not complex object values.

Comment: Please post text, not screenshots

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is not really with the `==` or `!=` operators, but rather the fact that in JavaScript no two objects are the same.

```js
var obj1 = {
  name: 'Joe'
}

var obj2 = {
  name: 'Joe'
}

var obj3 = obj1;

console.log(obj1 == obj2); // false (2 separate objects)
console.log(obj1 == obj3); // true (pointing to the same object)

var primitive1 = 'aaa';
var primitive2 = 'aaa';

console.log(primitive1 == primitive2); // true (compared by value)
```

When you compare those objects, JavaScript is simply comparing by reference. You have created 2 different objects in memory and JavaScript compares non-primitives by looking at the reference only.